# How to convert this formula from Numbers to Excel: INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($I;Sheet2::Table 1::B);3;4;TRUE;"Sheet2::Table 1"))?

Tags: excel, numbers, iwork

I provided this formula in a Numbers files that has two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2, and it works as I need:

`INDIRECT( ADDRESS( MATCH($I;Sheet2::Table 1::B) ;3;4;TRUE;"Sheet2::Table 1") )`

I explain what it does:

1. MATCH - in a cell of *Sheet1*, it compares the content of the column *I* (same row as it runs) with the column *B* of *Table 1* of *Sheet2*;
2. ADDRESS - when matched, it takes the position of cell (same row matched) but in column *C* from the *Table 1* of *Sheet2*;
3. INDIRECT - it takes the content of the cell addressed before.

Now, I need to use it in the original Excel file and I think I'm missing something...(and I can't save the Numbers file in to Excel).

how can I convert it?

Comment: Look into referencing worksheets in Excel formulas

Comment: I did...and also selecting cells, sheets...it gives error

Comment: Where is this formula, inside a table? Does Table 1 on Sheet2 have headers (I presume not as you reference a column Letter)?

Comment: The formula is in an entire column in Table 1 Sheet1. Both tables have headers.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using INDEX MATCH

Comment: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH([@<Column I's Header>],Table2[<Column B's Header>],0),3,4,1,"Sheet2"))